# Cannot connect to the Internet through proxy server in Windows system

Tags: windows, browser, proxy

My Windows 8.1 system has recently been experiencing problems with proxy in such a way that I cannot use any proxy server software e.g. Freegate, Psiphon3, etc. I run the proxy, open up a browser and enter a web address but the connection simply times out and no pages open, with the IE saying "The proxy server isn't responding" and Firefox just timing out.
[image]
Nevertheless, I have no problem opening websites without a proxy. My Firefox proxy settings are set to system proxy. Interestingly, when I open a website in non-proxy mode (no proxy running), the status bar shows (in Firefox) "Connecting to 127.0.0.1". 
[image]
This happens for all websites, whereas I don't find any proxy set for the system. For example, the following command presumably shows the system is set to connect directly to the Internet.
It is noteworthy that I formerly used to employ VPN proxies such as Cisco AnyConnect and OpenConnect software, but have failed to use them as well after appearance of this problem. Additionally, I have run [Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) several times and checked "reset the proxy settings" but with no luck. One more thing, even when Firefox is set to "no proxy", the status bar still keeps showing "Connecting to 127.0.0.1" when opening a page.
[image]

Comment: The proxy software you are using, are you running it locally, or on a remote machine?
If its locally, try adjusting the IP adress settings to the given IP adress of your machine.

Comment: @doenoe it is run locally. As a matter of fact, updating Windows solved most of the problem, but still see Firefox trying to connect to 127.0.01 when I open a website.